# HTML Inline CSS and Image Resolution

Tags: html, css

With the following code how can I incorporate all of the elements into inline CSS? (i.e. using a table, or background tag, etc.) And how can I decrease and increase the height and width of an image but still keep its resolution the same?

Please give some code on how to fix this.

```
<style>
body {background-color: powderblue;}
p    {font-family: Tohoma
h1   {color: red; font-family: Times New Roman;}
</style>
<body>
<img border="1" src="http://cdn.spacetelescope.org/archives/images/screen/heic1808a.jpg"></a></center>
<h1> Do you have unnecessary money sitting around? </h1>
(Rough draft text)<br>

<p>Hi Thomas, <br>
SAMPLE TEXT</p><br><br>


<p>
Sincerely, <br>
___ ____</p>

<img border="0" src="http://ec.europa.eu/research/headlines/news/images/11_12_17_small.jpg"></a></center>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are trying to send an email with CSS, so I can imagine what kind of problems you are experiencing.

I suggest you to use one of the several free template that you can found online, some of them are well done and tested with every mail client you may think of.

If you are on a hurry and need to solve quickly your problem with external CSS I suggest you a free tool that does exactly what you need: moves CSS to inline style attributes --> [CSS Inliner Tool](https://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/)